# Ektron multisite split

Tags: ektron

I have an Ektron multi-site installation and would like to split one of the sites into a separate installation. Any ideas on how to do this?

I have made a new CMS400 website. But do not know how to export the data from the multi-site and import it to the new database e.g

- Page Layouts
- Smart Form Configurations
- Library Content
- HTML Content
- Any Assets

And anything else I have left out that you think is important.

NOTE : Both websites are Ektron 8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup an esync relationship between the current database and a minsite install database, then use the esync function to do a manual sync of the folder for the site you want to copy.

Comment: Curious as to why this received a down vote. Can you think of a better way to copy the data from a single CMS folder from one server to another?